# Can DD-WRT work with TP-Link WR841N

Tags: wireless-router, dd-wrt, firmware

Can DD-WRT be installed on a TP-Link WR841N router? [This page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#TP-Link) lists only the WR841ND versions as being supported - but is there any significant difference between them?

Comment: If your router is not listed it means DD-WRT has either not been built to support your router or its not been tested.  In either case you should assume its NOT safe to install DD-WRT on your router.  If you ignore this advice, and install it anyways, research on how you might unbrick your router.  The firmware must be specifically built to support the broadband in your router, and YES, different models of the same "router" can contain different broadband chips.  What those differences are easily researched, I have not done so for your router, because its easier to let you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ramhound!

For anyone who wonders - the two routers TP-Link TL-WR841N and TL-WR841ND are identical except for the (D)etachable antennae in the WR841ND model ([link](http://dfarq.homeip.net/the-difference-between-the-tp-link-tl-wr841n-and-tl-wr841nd/)). And DD-WRT can in fact run on both ([link](http://dfarq.homeip.net/how-i-upgraded-a-tp-link-tl-wr841n-to-dd-wrt/)).